How to set the working directory for a Windows service created with pywin32
While creating a systemd service in linux, I could specify a WorkingDirectory in the service unit file. Is there any way to configure the working directory for a Windows service as well. I have some configuration files which needs to be read by the service at startup.
I'm using pywin32 interface for creating the service in Windows.

you can not - services.exe hardcoded pass 0 in place lpCurrentDirectory. but if you control service by self, you can by self select any folder

I was able to set the working directory of the service from the service run method.
